# SQLite exception: "no such function: BigCount" when using "count" calling OData service with EntityFramework provider

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, sqlite, odata

I use EF5 over SQLite database (using System.Data.SQLite 1.0.90.0). The entities are exposed via OData service

```
public sealed class MyService : DataService<MyEntities>
```

When I query my entities from inside my app it works ok, for example

```
using (var ents = new MyEntities) 
{
    var count = ents.SomeEntity.Select(ent => ent).Count();
}
```

When I send a request from browser like this

```
http://localhost:8737/MyService/SomeEntity
```

it also works fine, it returns me the list of my entities.

But when I create a following request

```
http://localhost:8737/MyService/SomeEntity/$count
```

OR

I query the service by service reference from some client app (and my query contains `Count()`), I get an Exception

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQL logic error or missing database
>       no such function: BigCount

I suppose that when the SQL request is generated it contains aggregate function BIGCOUNT which SQLite doesn't have. If I change my database provider to SQL Server, then everything is absolutely fine. I don't know what I can do to change the way the request is generated. I tried to switch to Entity Framework 6 + System.Data.SQLite 1.0.94.0 but it's no use. I tried to stick to EF5 and change the versions of System.Data.SQLite to previous ones but nothing changed. The only difference I had was that my [earlier problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169990/sqlite-entityframework-mapping-problems-edm-double-is-not-compatible-with-sqlit) was "solved" (in quotes because I would not call something I don't understand a solution) when I used the EF6+SQLITE1.0.94.0.

UPDATE 23/12/2014

We solved this problem by examining the System.Data.SQLite sources, finding the place where the "bigcount" keyword was incorrectly used, fixing it for our needs and then rebuilding the library.

As stated [here](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mySQL/docs/CanonicalFunctions.html#note2) the BigCount should be compiled to COUNT() in all databases except SQL Server. It looks like BigCount was compiled just to BigCount, or sth like that.

Rebuilding the library turned to be tricky itself, and since I'm only a little Junior yet, so my Team Lead did that part and I can't tell the details, which I didn't have time to dive deeper in. At least, it's a direction you can use to solve the same problem.

Comment: I encountered the same problem an opened a ticket for it at [system.data.sqlite.org](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/info/76c2eaadc0297696). If you can provide more details about how you fixed it, this could speed up to get it included in the official version.

Comment: Thank you, @linac. Unfortunately, I couldn't add comments to that ticket but I added an answer to this question with detailed step-by-step instructions to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the error `SQL logic error or missing database\r\nno such function: BigCount` and here are the detailed step-by-step instructions I used to update the code to resolve the issue on a Windows operating system:

1. Download [fossil](https://www.fossil-scm.org) and extract fossil.exe to your `<working>` directory
2. Open a normal command prompt
3. Run `cd <working>`
4. Run `fossil clone https://system.data.sqlite.org/ sds.fossil`
5. Run `fossil open sds.fossil`
6. Run `fossil update <release-tag>`

   For example, `fossil update release-1.0.105.2`
7. Update `.\System.Data.SQLite.Linq\SQL Generation\SqlGenerator.cs`:
   a. un-comment lines 1978 - 1983
   b. replace line 1982 with the following line:

   `aggregateResult.Append("COUNT");`
8. Run `cd Setup`
9. Run `set_YYYY.bat`

   For example, to build the net451 binaries, run `set_2013.bat`
10. Run `build.bat ReleaseManagedOnly`
11. Remove the references to `System.Data.SQLite.Linq` and `System.Data.SQLite.EF6` from the ASP.NET Web project
12. Add references to the new `System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll` and `System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll` from `<working>\bin\2013\Release\bin` in the ASP.NET Web project

Sources:

[System.Data.SQLite Source Code](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/source.wiki)
[System.Data.SQLite Build Procedures](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/build.wiki)
[System.Data.SQLite Ticket UUID 76c2eaadc0297696b2c5fb10d41a22325f56f9b9](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview/76c2eaadc0297696b2c5fb10d41a22325f56f9b9)